# KQL Query to retrieve Azure Subscription Name, Resource Group, Resource Name, Resource Type, Tags and Location

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-resource-manager, kql

I would like to retrieve all the resource names along with their types belonging to a particular subscription and resource group, along with the tags of the resources.
I should be able to dump them in a CSV file where the first column would be subscription, then resource group followed by resource name, type and tags. I should be able to filter the CSV as to what i need to see.
I need to run this for all my subscriptions in a particular tenant so that i get this information for all subscriptions in my tenant.
Can anyone please help me writing a KQL query for this so that i can run from the portal.
Thanks

Comment: kql query to do that? it's not a good idea. you'd better using powershell scripts to do that.

Answer (score 7):

had a similar challenge with KQL to provide a user friendly names for Subscriptions in Azure Workbooks. I found a solution on [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915958-azure-governance/suggestions/35885221-ability-to-retreive-subscription-name-given-subscr)

The trick is to list the subscriptionnames from the table resourcecontainers and then join the results with your resources query

The answer to your question will look like this:

```
resources
| join kind=inner (
    resourcecontainers
    | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
    | project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name)
    on subscriptionId
| project subscriptionName, resourceGroup, name, type, tags
```

Answer (score 3):

Using KQL in Azure Resource Graph is actually an ideal way to retrieve this information.  You can run the KQL queries from the Azure Portal using Resource Graph Explorer then export (or use PowerShell with the Search-AzGraph cmdlet and pipe to Export-Csv).

Resource Graph allows queries to the ARM graph backend using KQL, which is an extremely powerful and preferred method to access Azure configuration data.  All subscriptions in the tenant are in scope by default (if checked off).

Please review Resource Graph concepts and query samples in Microsoft's docs:

- [Explore your Azure resources with Resource Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/explore-resources)
- [Starter Resource Graph query samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/starter)
- [Advanced Resource Graph query samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/advanced)

Query below; if you choose to export all subscriptions and RGs at once just remove the subscriptionId and resourceGroup where clauses:

```
resources | where subscriptionId == "subscription-id-here" | where resourceGroup == "rg-name-here" | project subscriptionId, resourceGroup, name, type, tags
```